# How to display another icon when tab is active in Ionic React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have this tab-bar where active elements have another icon than inactive:

[image]

It will also change the item with the `onIonTabsDidChange`-hook from `IonTabBar`:

```js
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<string>()

return 
<IonTabBar onIonTabsDidChange={(event) => setActiveTab(event.detail.tab)}>
  <IonTabButton  tab="explore" href="/explore">
    {activeTab === 'explore' ? <HomeIconSolid /> : <HomeIcon />}
  </IonTabButton>
  <IonTabButton tab="game" href="/game" >
    {activeTab === 'game' ? <PlayIconSolid/> : <PlayIcon />}
  </IonTabButton>
</IonTabBar>
```

My problem is that when the page is loaded first time (without any change Tab events) it will not display the correct item:

[image]

How can **I achieve to set the icon at first load** as well?

- I'm not able to define a default! Because users could enter the page from a different url (e.g.: game is the first page)
- I searched for an init / load hook but didn't find one

Comment: How do you know the current URL? In my point of view, you could just take the income URL and parse it for your desired icon. And you could use `useEffect` to achieve what you want.

Comment: @EsdrasXavier I'm using react-router. Your idea is to check the route and use this information to set the activeTab state?

Comment: Yes, you could set the initial value of `setState`, or you could use `useEffect(() => setActiveTab(router.url), []);`, and when the component mounts it will execute this method, and update the current state.